# Compare Call Trees option is disabled in instrument

Tags: ios, compare, profiling, xcode-instruments, xcode9.4

I have two runs in instrument. Second run is optimized version of the first run. I want to compare them but while selecting Instrument option from menu, the Compare Call Trees.. option is disabled. How can this option be enabled?

Comment: Can you compare call trees using the version of Instruments in the Xcode 10 beta? I found that comparing call trees was always disabled in Xcode 9 with no way to enable it.

Comment: @MarkSzymczyk There is no option of compare call trees in Xcode 10 beta.

Comment: You found the answer to your question. Apple removed the Compare Call Trees feature from Instruments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Compare Call Trees** option was disabled in Xcode 9 and there is no feature **Compare Call Trees** from Xcode 10.